# recycled twice! Runtime Exception in TypedArray

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm receiving some crash reports from devices using android L preview, the issue is

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [17, ...... ] recycled twice!
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.recycle(TypedArray.java:869)
```

Can't see the code because Android L is still not available, How can I check if the TypedArray is already recycled?

I actually found that the call to recycle is called twice, but anyway, why throw a exception now breaking potentially old working code (even if it's incorrect to call recycle twice).

Comment: Have you noticed the documentation change in _TypedArray.recycle()_ ? It has changed to ; "Recycle the TypedArray, to be re-used by a later caller. After calling this function you must not ever touch the typed array again."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Due to changes in TypedArray pooling in L, calling TypedArray.recycle() twice or calling a getter on TypedArray after recycle() is not safe. This has never been correct app behavior and prior to L may have introduced subtle errors.